# IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument python write

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing to network share and this is the piece of code which writes

```
while not created:
    fileName = ''.join(random.choice(CANDIDATE_CHARS) for x in range(len))
    fullPath = os.path.join(base, fileName)
    if not os.path.exists(fullPath):
        filesize = random.randint(fileSizeLowerLim, fileSizeUpperLim)
        logger.info("Creating file %s, with size %d" %(fullPath, filesize))
        with open(fullPath, 'wb') as fout:
            if filesize > 0:
               fout.write(os.urandom(filesize * 1048576))
               sizeLimit -= filesize
        allFiles.append(fullPath)
        created = True
logger.info("Created file %s, now limit is %d" %(fullPath, sizeLimit))
```

And I get this error:

```
fout.write(os.urandom(filesize * 1048576))
  IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
  job remoteMachine finished ended with rc = 1
  remoteMachine finished and it failed
```

And when I looked at file it was generated but had no data. Is there something I missed in python?

I am running the script on windows 7 using 32 bit python.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your "urandom" buffer exceeds 64MB and thus hits a Windows [operating system limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899149), which has similarly affected others when [writing to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925840/132382).