# Python logger throwing IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, measurement, ioerror

I'm getting an error from trying to write to a file and log normal text. Here's my logger output:

```
Bad measurement: 40.74478609626E-9,81.48235294118E-9,163.01491596639E-9,244.51470588235E-9,326.05084670232E-9,407.55387700535E-9,489.09705882353E-9,570.63334914611E-9,652.15799632353E-9,733.68823529412E-9,815.19491596639E-9,1.30423299632E-6,2.60858733660E-6,6.11542963458E-6,13.04562372549E-6,26.09313266488E-6,39.13227058824E-6,52.17394175579E-6,78.25093569519E-6,163.01165588235E-6,305.64046063025E-6,611.30138063025E-6,815.07555294118E-6,1.01882401751E-3,1.22261084479E-3,2.44530079118E-3,9.9100E+037

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 53, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Projects/main.py", line 209, in <module>
    path = "data.txt"
  File "C:/Projects/main.py", line 177, in run_period
    logger.info("Error: {}".format(repr(e)))
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Context: I'm reading measurements from an oscilloscope and saving to a file. On occasion, the data from the scope will be corrupted, so I've wrapped the write in a try-catch:

```
try:
    f.write(",".join(acq) + "\n")
    cnt += 1
except Exception as e:
    logger.info("Bad measurement: {}".format(",".join(acq)))
    logger.info("Error: {}".format(repr(e)))
    logger.info("The measurement couldn't be written to the file")
```

Yes, bad practice not to use a specific exception, I know, but I'm just trying to get my data and get out.

Logger is assigned to

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("runScript")
```

I thought this might have something to do with [the Windows OS buffer limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366470/ioerror-errno-22-invalid-argument-python-write), but my file is only a few hundred kilobytes.

The function throwing the error is part of PyCharm. Here's the function:

```
def run_file(file, globals=None, locals=None, is_module=False):
    module_name = None
    entry_point_fn = None
    if is_module:
        file, _,  entry_point_fn = file.partition(':')
        module_name = file
        filename = get_fullname(file)
        if filename is None:
            sys.stderr.write("No module named %s\n" % file)
            return
        else:
            file = filename

    if os.path.isdir(file):
        new_target = os.path.join(file, '__main__.py')
        if os.path.isfile(new_target):
            file = new_target

    if globals is None:
        m = save_main_module(file, 'pydev_run_in_console')

        globals = m.__dict__
        try:
            globals['__builtins__'] = __builtins__
        except NameError:
            pass  # Not there on Jython...

    if locals is None:
        locals = globals

    if not is_module:
        sys.path.insert(0, os.path.split(file)[0])

    print('Running %s' % file)
    try:
        if not is_module:
            pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
        else:
            # treat ':' as a seperator between module and entry point function
            # if there is no entry point we run we same as with -m switch. Otherwise we perform
            # an import and execute the entry point
            if entry_point_fn:
                mod = __import__(module_name, level=0, fromlist=[entry_point_fn], globals=globals, locals=locals)
                func = getattr(mod, entry_point_fn)
                func()
            else:
                # Run with the -m switch
                import runpy
                if hasattr(runpy, '_run_module_as_main'):
                    runpy._run_module_as_main(module_name)
                else:
                    runpy.run_module(module_name)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

    return globals
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Hello, could you show what is assigned to logger?

Comment: @roganjosh The rest of it's just the file and function this is in.

Comment: Occasionally an `IOError` on `write` is because of a real I/O error (your disk is going bad, you're writing to a network share that's been interrupted, etc.), but more commonly it's just something like you've accidentally opened the file in an incorrect mode, or closed it, or done a `seek` to an invalid position.

Comment: Can you move `",".join(acq` out of the `try` block, in case it's an exception for *reading* the data?

Comment: Anyway, from what you've posted here, it looks like the `IOError` comes from the `logger.info`, and there's some other exception from the `f.write` that we can't see because you're just doing a bare `except:` and throwing that information away. Can you show us the traceback you get without that, or at least change it to `except Exception as e:` and print(repr(e))` or something?

Comment: @abarnert Okay, trying that and rerunning now. The error happens about an hour into the measurements...

Comment: @Ellburrito Since it takes an hour to repro, try to get everything in one cycle. In particular, if you do still get an exception from `logger.info`, please copy the whole traceback this time, instead of just giving us the one line. (Also, if this is Python 3, you shouldn't have to change any code to get all of this—the traceback for the `logger.info` should have a long section saying this exception was raised while handling another exception, and include the traceback for the `f.write` within it.)

Comment: @Ellburrito Remove try/except statement and post here the whole exception you will get. You will get the full traceback and it will be much easier to debug the error.

Comment: What's the content and type of `acq` variable?

Comment: @Samuel `acq` contains a list of floats; they're shown in the first line.

Comment: `pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)` is the method that raises exception. Please paste this line and code of executed python file

Comment: I suspect the problem may have something to do with PyDev's console isn't enough of a real stderr for `logging` to use it as `stderr`. But it's odd that the first log message that you added prints fine. There must be something different about `repr(e)`. Maybe a non-ASCII character? You'd expect that to raise a `UnicodeEncodeError`, but maybe PyCharm is trying to do something to handle that and failing? If you could log `str(repr(e).encode('unicode-escape'))`? Or can you just try `print(repr(e))` instead of logging?

Comment: Or, simplest of all, just remove the `except` and let it print out the traceback.